# Apply condition if radio button is unchecked

Tags: jquery

how to apply condition if radio button is unchecked. if `#radio_button_id_1` is unchecked it shown confirmation `confirm('You want domestic?')`. If user clicked same radio button more than once it should not show `confirm('You want domestic?')` .

If user click radio button `#radio_button_id_2` and again clicked `#radio_button_id_1` than it should show the `confirm('You want domestic?')`

HTML:

```
<input  type="radio" id="#radio_button_id_1" name="shipping_information" 
        class="form-radio icustom-control-input">
<label> Domestic <label>

<input  type="radio" id="#radio_button_id_2" 
        name="shipping_information" class="form-radio icustom-control-input">
<label> internation<label>
```

My javascript

```
$(document).on('click', '#radio_button_id_1', function(event){
  // apply condition if radio button is already not checked/Clciked
   if (confirm('You want domestic?')) {
        
      } else {
        event.preventDefault();
      }

 });

$(document).on('click', '#radio_button_id_2', function(event){
  // apply condition if radio button is already not checked/Clciked
   if (confirm('You want internation?')) {
        
      } else {
        event.preventDefault();
      }

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add and remove class base on your click.

```
$(document).on('click', '#radio_button_id', function(event){
  // apply condition if it not click more one time
if(('#radio_button_id').hasClass( "I-allready-clicked" )){
//do you stuff here
// remove the class for the next time
    ('#radio_button_id').removeClass("I-allready-clicked");
}else{
     ('#radio_button_id').addClass("I-allready-clicked");
}
   if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
        
      } else {
        event.preventDefault();
      }

 });
```

Comment: I think you do not have to write `removeClass()` and `addClass()`. The function `toggleClass(<className>)` does the same. It is just a small improvement for you. Never mind...

Comment: @Reporter you are right, but the main issue here (before the questioner change the question was to detect if the button was clicked or not. The adding/removing class was only minor indication.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is to set a an attribute on the button that will tell you if it has been clicked or not.

```
$(document).on('click', '#radio_button_id', function(event) {
  if ($(this).attr("clicked") == "true" ? false : true) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
    } else {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    $(this).attr("clicked", "true");
  }
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).on('click', '#radio_button_id', function(event) {
  if ($(this).attr("clicked") == "true" ? false : true) {
    if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {

    } else {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    $(this).attr("clicked", "true");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="radio_button_id">click me only once</button>
```

If you want to know how many time's it has been clicked you can use the same method.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#radio_button_id', function(event) {
  var clicked = $(this).attr("clicked") == undefined ? 1 : +$(this).attr("clicked");
  if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {

  } else {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  console.log("you have clicked the button " + clicked + " times")
  $(this).attr("clicked", (clicked + 1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="radio_button_id">click me only once</button>
```

Comment: I have two radio button. if the radio button 1 already checked than it should not show confirm message but if I click second radio button and again click on radio button 1 its show the confirm message

Comment: @PankajKumar that was not part of your question, please update your question with all relative information and code (html, jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can use dataset of element, with jquery  `data()` for saving state of input same as :

```js
$(document).on("click", 'input:radio',function (e) {
    if ($(this).data("checked")) {
        $(this).prop("checked",false).data("checked", false);
    } else {
      let text = $(this).data('confirm')
      if (confirm(text)) {
        $('input:radio').data("checked", false);
        $(this).prop("checked", true).data("checked",true)
      } else {
        e.preventDefault()
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  type="radio" id="radio_button_id_1" name="shipping_information" class="form-radio icustom-control-input" data-confirm="You want domestic">
<label> Domestic <label>

<input  type="radio" id="radio_button_id_2" name="shipping_information" class="form-radio icustom-control-input" data-confirm="You want internation">
<label> internation<label>
```

Comment: when I click on cancel button it still select the radio button. in case if user select the cancel button its should not select Domestic

Comment: I 've update unchecked for it

Comment: First i click on domestic and confirm yes than clicked international and confirm cancel again click on international  both radio button become unchecked

Comment: If i check same button twice it unchecked the the both button. if checked the button more than once no message but radio button should not unchecked

Comment: Please try again